# SASS function to iterate nth-child(n+1) and lighten/darken($color, 5n%)

Tags: css, function, sass, scss-mixins

I use a lot of SASS/SCSS, but don't usually use <del>complex</del> any functions. My current need seems like the perfect use-case for a function but not sure how to loop like this in SASS/SCSS.

I need a stepped colour pattern that changes the background colour of each additional list item.

I need to repeat this task with various base colours, and I was hoping someone could help with a concise SASS/SCSS function that can replace this block of SCSS, which increments the `li:nth-child()` by 1 (n+1) and increments `background-color: lighten($color, 5%)` by 5% (5n) for each `li`.

```
.service {
  background-color: $color;

  .list {
    li:nth-child(2) {
      background-color: lighten($color,5%);
    }
    li:nth-child(3) {
      background-color: lighten($color,10%);
    }
    li:nth-child(4) {
      background-color: lighten($color,15%);
    }
    li:nth-child(5) {
      background-color: lighten($color,20%);
    }
    li:nth-child(6) {
      background-color: lighten($color,25%);
    }
    li:nth-child(7) {
      background-color: lighten($color,30%);
    }
  }
}
```

Let me know if any clarification is required. Many thanks in advance for your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can try :

```
@for $i from 2 through 7 {
  li:nth-child(#{$i}) {
      background-color: lighten($color, ($i - 1) * 5%);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
$alpha: 5;
$color: red;
@for $i from 1 through 4 {
    li:nth-child(#{$i}) {
        background-color: lighten($color, $alpha + 0%);
    }

    $alpha: $alpha + 5;
}
```

Output:

```
li:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #ff1a1a;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #ff3333;
}

li:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #ff4d4d;
}

li:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: #ff6666;
}
```

You can just change the `from` and `trough` values to 2 and 7 or what suits you best.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer also delivers result, but have selected the more concise solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$colors: lighten(red, 5%), lighten(red, 10%), lighten(red, 15%), lighten(red, 20%);

@each $color in $colors {
    $i: index($colors, $color);
    li:nth-child(#{$i}) {
        background-color: nth($color, 1);
    }
}
```

Out put like:

```
li:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: #ff1a1a;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: #ff3333;
}

li:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: #ff4d4d;
}

li:nth-child(4) {
    background-color: #ff6666;
}
```